# Открыть .db файл из File explorer в стороннем редакторе

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть файл *.db и есть программа на компьютере для просмотра .db файлов. Причем она назначена по умолчанию для *.db файлов. Я хочу чтобы двойным щелчком по *.db файлу в Android Studio Device File Explorer у меня открывалась база именно в этой проге. На данный момент получаю ошибку "Unable to open file". Выбрал тип открытия "Filed opened in associate application". Android studio 3.1

Если просто сохранить файл на компьютер и открыть его, то все хорошо.

Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

File -> Settings... -> Editor -> File Types.
Можно настроить, с помощью чего открывать файлы. Главное не забыть потом нажать "Apply"